# Hydrogen passes "-f" to ArgumentParser

Tags: ipython, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am trying to run the following code in Atom's Hydrogen package

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()
```

which produces the following error

ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3883). 
Simple workaround is running `import sys; sys.argv=['']; del sys;`.